# Angular general version is lower than local

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have tried to use several suggestions from posts\questions in Stackoverflow in order to update my Angular version, in addition to the `https://update.angular.io/`.
This thing is inside a specific project it looks like the Angular version in the latest(`~7.2.0`) while , when using `npm angular --version` is `6.4.1`.
What am I doing wrong, if at all..?

Comment: check your package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `6.4.1` is your npm version it seems that npm ignored the `angular` word, try `npm --version` you will get the same output

use `ng --version` instead

Answer (score 0):

try `ng --version`

in my case, i ran this in the folder where my local version was older than my global version... I got the following message:

> Your global Angular CLI version (6.1.0) is greater than your local
>   version (6.0.0). The local Angular CLI version is used.
>
> To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch
>   false".